# phpMyadmin returns 0 rows in sql query

Tags: mysql

This is my query

`SELECT * from status_votes where vote = 'like' and status_id = 1 and item_poster = 'LUcase'`

It returns 0 rows, but when I view the table there are rows which match my query 
[image: phpmyadmin displaying the row]

Please let me know where I am going wrong...

Comment: please provide table structure...

Comment: check Abhay answer.. it should solve your problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption is that perhaps there are leading or trailing spaces in your data that aren't visible looking at the values in phpMyAdmin. Can you please try to edit a record in phpMyAdmin and see if it actually contain spaces.

Please try running this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM status_votes
WHERE TRIM(vote) = 'like'
AND status_id = 1
AND TRIM(item_poster) = 'LUcase';
```

If that doesn't work, can you please share your table structure?

Comment: i edited the record and the field shows LUcase����������
Why is this?

Comment: @MarshallMathews, I can't actually comment, for certain, on this. It depends on where the data is being inserted into the field. But my guess is that item_poster contains some special characters, which phpMyAdmin isn't able to render correctly. If possible, perhaps you can try running the select query in the MySQL command-line client.

Comment: ok im doing a 2 way encryption using mcrypt and that causes the weird characters..
is there a better way for 2 way encryption

Comment: This is weird. If you are encrypting your data, it is obvious that `item_poster = 'LUcase'` will never give a match. You will have to either decrypt the column before doing the comparison or encrypt "LUcase" before passing it into the query

Comment: yes i am decrypting it before doing the query and it gave the empty spaces, well nevermind.
I used base64 encode/decode and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Try reducing your query to see which WHERE clause is causing problems:

Try these ONE line at a time:

```
SELECT * from status_votes where vote = 'like' and status_id = 1 and item_poster = 'LUcase'
SELECT * from status_votes where vote = 'like' and status_id = 1 and item_poster = 'Lucase'
SELECT * from status_votes where vote = 'like' and item_poster = 'LUcase'
SELECT * from status_votes where status_id = 1 and item_poster = 'LUcase'
SELECT * from status_votes where vote = 'like' 
SELECT * from status_votes where status_id = 1 
SELECT * from status_votes where item_poster = 'LUcase'
SELECT * from status_votes
```

It shouldn't be hard to isolate the problem...

Comment: Any query with item_poster returns 0 rows, this is weird.

Comment: So item_poster is your problem. Find out if there are any spaces around it. Try `item_poster like '%LUcase%'`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `status_votes`
 WHERE `vote` = 'like'
   AND `status_id` = '1'
   AND `item_poster` = 'LUcase'
```

Comment: are you trying it from phpmyadmin? or from your php script?

Comment: phpmyadmin, like i commented in the other answer
Anything without item_poster in the where clause returns rows :( STUPID MYSQL